# problem when trying to issue "composer update" command in vs code terminal on linux

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, ini

I want to give the command "composer update" in a folder but this error always appears below, the same error also appears when I write in the terminal "php --version", "laravel --version" or even "composer --version" . I don't know what the problem could be.
Previously I had downloaded version 7 of php, but I had to uninstall and install version 8.1

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'bz2' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20210902/bz2 (/usr/lib/php/20210902/bz2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20210902/bz2.so (/usr/lib/php/20210902/bz2.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'curl' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20210902/curl (/usr/lib/php/20210902/curl: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20210902/curl.so (/usr/lib/php/20210902/curl.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'gd' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20210902/gd (/usr/lib/php/20210902/gd: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20210902/gd.so (/usr/lib/php/20210902/gd.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'mbstring' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20210902/mbstring (/usr/lib/php/20210902/mbstring: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20210902/mbstring.so (/usr/lib/php/20210902/mbstring.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'mysqli' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20210902/mysqli (/usr/lib/php/20210902/mysqli: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20210902/mysqli.so (/usr/lib/php/20210902/mysqli.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_mysql' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20210902/pdo_mysql (/usr/lib/php/20210902/pdo_mysql: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20210902/pdo_mysql.so (/usr/lib/php/20210902/pdo_mysql.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_sqlite' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20210902/pdo_sqlite (/usr/lib/php/20210902/pdo_sqlite: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20210902/pdo_sqlite.so (/usr/lib/php/20210902/pdo_sqlite.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'xsl' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20210902/xsl (/usr/lib/php/20210902/xsl: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20210902/xsl.so (/usr/lib/php/20210902/xsl.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module "exif" is already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module "FFI" is already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module "fileinfo" is already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module "ftp" is already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module "gettext" is already loaded in Unknown on line 0
```

I tried to uncomment these things that are in the error in the php.ini file, install composer again, but it still didn't work.

Comment: You have updated your PHP version, so the extension need to install for supported php version.  Run, sudo apt-get install php-bz2,  restart Apache and check for the very first line error removed for bz2.

Comment: If running `php --version` throws this error, how is this problem related to Laravel, Composer, or [tag:ini]?

Answer (score 0):

"PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'bz2'", indicates that PHP (Hypertext Preprocessor) is unable to load the 'bz2' dynamic library during startup. The 'bz2' extension is responsible for supporting the Bzip2 compression algorithm in PHP scripts.

Verify the extension is installed by using command:

**php -m**

If the 'bz2' extension is not listed, you'll need to install it. On Linux, you can usually do this using your package manager. For example, on Ubuntu, you can run:
**sudo apt-get install php-bz2**

Comment: thank you very much!! the error disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

Run this script, install all necessary extensions.

```
sudo apt-get install -y php8.1-cli php8.1-common php8.1-mysql php8.1-zip php8.1-gd php8.1-mbstring php8.1-curl php8.1-xml php8.1-bcmath
```

Reference

> https://computingforgeeks.com/how-to-install-php-on-ubuntu-2/

Comment: thank you very much!! I was able to run the "composer update" command without any problems.